# Top questions by tag and period

Tags: support, discussion, api-v2, api, documentation

I want to get via API the most **voted questions** from the **latest week** (for example) from a **specified tag** (`php`, for example).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. On the documentation page we find all needed information:

Example:

> /2.1/questions?

- pagesize=50
- fromdate=1371859200
- todate=1372550400
- order=desc
- sort=votes
- tagged=javascript
- site=stackoverflow

> https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?pagesize=50&fromdate=1371859200&todate=1372550400&order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=javascript&site=stackoverflow

[**DOCUMENTATION**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions)